# JUnit test for AWS S3 Camel XML DSL route in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, junit, apache-camel, spring-test

I have configured an XML camel route as mentioned below

```
<route>
        <from uri="sftp://testuser@localhost?password=test&amp;delete=true" />
        <setHeader name="CamelAwsS3Key">
             <simple>${in.header.camelFileName}</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="aws-s3://myTestBucket?accessKey=******&amp;secretKey=RAW(******)&amp;deleteAfterWrite=false&amp;region=AP_SOUTH_1" />
    </route>
```

I ahve been trying to create test cases for the same. *contextLoads()* tries to access the s3 localtion in real time which i want to prevent.
Saw there are solutions with LocalStack, is there any other way i can test a scenario without other libraries?